# AJAX client tool for interrogating endpoints

Tags: ajax

Are there any AJAX client tools for interrogating ajax endpoints?

I am using firebug for development and have installed some addons for manipulating the request headers.

However, I am finding this to be quite unproductive as I need to set the `X-Requested-With` in the header whenever I want to test my AJAX endpoint and then remove it for testing my pages normally.

I am looking for a GUI tool which allows me to point it to an AJAX endpoint and craft a request, be it a JSON request or just a standard GET/POST request.

Something equivalent to [Pinta](http://code.google.com/p/pinta/) (for testing AMF requests) in the AJAX world would be nice.

Do any tools like this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [HttpRequest](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/) (a FireFox addon) that can do this. Simply just set the request header `x-requested-with` to `XMLHttpRequest` and away you go!